# Running existing production Java applications in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've been reading up on Spark and am very interested in the ability to allocate computation across scalable compute clusters.  We have production stream processing code (5K lines written in Java 9) which handles AMQP message processing, that we would like to run in a Spark cluster.
However, I feel like I must misunderstand the basic premise of Spark.  On the one hand, it runs Java and we should be able to run our applications with it, but on the other hand it seems (from the documentation) that all code must be rewritten to the Spark API (using Dataframes/Datasets).  Is this true?  Can Java applications be used as-is with Spark, or must they be rewritten?  This seems like a major limitation or rather a showstopper for us.

I think, ideally, we would want to use Spark to handle high level message routing (using the Structured Streaming API), which would hand off the message to our Java application to handle computation, database writes etc.  The core part of our code is single class interface and Spark could map the message to that class instance.  Hence, there would likely be many, many instances processing messages in parallel both within each machine instance and distributed across the cluster.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

for your question **Can Java applications be used as-is with Spark, or must they be rewritten?**

Yes, you have to rewrite the data interaction layer.

spark reads the source data in the form of rdd/dataframe, in your case its streaming Dataframes/Datasets.

Spark parallel processing/job scheduling is based on these dataset/dataframe

Dataframes/dataset is equivalent to an Array which is storing data on multiple nodes.

so if you have a logic in java that iterate a list and writes to file

```
conn=openFile(..)
Array[value].foreach{
  value-> {
  updatedValue=/**your business logic on the value**/
  conn.write(updatedValue)
  }
}
```

in spark you have to deal with the dataframe

```
dataframe[value].map{ value->
        updatedValue =/**your business logic on the value**/  <-- reuse your logic here
      }.saveToFile(/**file path**/)
```

hope you can see the difference, you can reuse your business logic, 
but spark has to handle the dataflow either read/write(recommended).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm fine with reworking the input/output sections to work with RDDs.  I'm just concerned with the business logic, which Spark should (to my mind) have nothing to do with.

Comment: I guess my question more about the several thousand lines of business logic and 100+ classes, which are all internal to the core code.  As long as those can be left as-is, I'm fine.

Comment: That will be little tricky, when you pass your logic into spark functions, task/data serialization comes to play. 
 Logic and its reference to outside object has to be closure serialized, it has to be independent to execute on any spark cluster node.
you have to find a boundary in your code base up to where you can run inside a spark function & things that has to run on driver node(local machine where you submit spark)
good discussion on serialization  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259196/understanding-sparks-closures-and-their-serialization)