# Running a Java Library on the spark executor without NotSerializableException

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am writing a spark application which uses java and spring boot to process rows. For every row it should perform some logic and save data into the database.

The logic that has to be performed uses some services defined in my application and some external libraries.

While running my service I am getting `NotSerializableException`.

My spark job and service is :

```
// It is a temperorary job, which would be removed after testing
public class HelloWorld implements Runnable, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    GraphRequestProcessor graphProcessor;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String sparkAppName = "hello-job";
        JavaSparkContext sparkCtx = new JavaSparkContext(getSparkConf(sparkAppName));
        JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sparkCtx.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
        rdd.map(new Function<Integer, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(integer);
                return integer;
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    
    public static SparkConf getSparkConf(String appName) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        String master = env.get("SPARK_MASTER");
        SparkConf sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .set("spark.kryo.registrator", "com.example.sparktest.AppKryoRegistrar");
        if (master != null) {
            sparkConfig.setMaster(master);
        } else {
            sparkConfig.setMaster("local[*]");
        }
        return sparkConfig;
    }
    
}
```

The graphRequestProcessor is actually used in the task. I am skipping calling it here, to keep the example simple. I have registered the GraphRequestProcessor and GraphRequestProcessorImpl in the kryo registrar. Since I am using kryo, I think the serialization would be handled by kryo itself.

After running my spark application, I am getting the error

```
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.example.graph.impl.GraphRequestProcessorImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fc280f7, value: com.example.graph.impl.GraphRequestProcessorImpl@4a225014)
    - field (class: com.example.graph.job.HelloWorld, name: graphRequestProcessor, type: interface com.example.graph.service.GraphRequestProcessor)
    - object (class com.example.graph.job.HelloWorld, com.example.graph.job.HelloWorld@65448932)
    - field (class: com.example.graph.job.HelloWorld$1, name: this$0, type: class com.example.graph.job.HelloWorld)
    - object (class com.example.graph.job.HelloWorld$1, com.example.graph.job.HelloWorld$1@1a2b23f2)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD$.$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1:(Lorg/apache/spark/api/java/function/Function;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$$Lambda$1942/0x0000000800d1e840, org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$$Lambda$1942/0x0000000800d1e840@1666e021)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:413)
    ... 13 more
```

I read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259196/understanding-sparks-closures-and-their-serialization) here and understood that Java might not be able to serialise my class. But how do I solve the above issue without making all my classes extend `Serializable` ? How do we manage serialisation for big java projects ?